# Yii, get value from other table with foreign key

Tags: php, yii, foreign-keys

I'm prety new to yii framework so i could use some help with something.
Lets say i got a table in my database with users, 1 of the profile fields is nationality.
In another table i got a lot of nationalities like this:

```
 id    Nationality    short
  1    Germany         DE
  2    France          FR
  3    Netherlands     NL
```

etc... about 60+ nationalities.
In the usertable, the user nationality is linked with this table, like this:

```
id    username    nationality
1      user            1
```

that means the nationality of user 1 = germany. but how can i select germany from the nationalities table when im in the profile view?

i hope im clear, else ask :)

greets,
stefan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need model classes for both tables, e.g.

```
class Profile extends CActiveRecord {
    ...
}

class Nationality extends CActiveRecord {
    ...
}
```

Then in the `Profile` model you need a relation *to* `Nationality`:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'nationality' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Nationality', 'nationality'),
    ),
}
```

The name of the relation `'nationality'` is how you refer to the related model, e.g.:

```
$profile = Profile::model()->findByPk($id);
echo $profile->nationality->short;
```

#### Resources

- [Has vs Belongs](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one)
- [Good schemas](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/227/guidelines-for-good-schema-design/)
- [Relational Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

Answer (score 2):

Tahts what relations are for: see [relational model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr):

```
'nationality' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Nationality', 'nationality')
```

Amd in your view, if you are using a [CDetailView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView) you can reference the nationality by its relation name, and call its attributes with dot notation:

```
nationality.short
```

read the [CDetailView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView) docs for more examples